# ERROR: Win32Exception: Host desconocido

Tags: c#, webservice, api

Tengo un servicio API y funciona correctamente, pero de la noche a la mañana me empezó a mandar este error, ¿a que se debe? que significa, la información esta aun en una base de datos en Azure. no se que signifique.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has cambiado de contraseña?

Comment: hola, la contraseña de que?

Comment: la del servidor o la de la bbdd

Comment: pues antes de republicar el servicio cambie la contraseña del .Publish que me provee el Azure en "userPWD: kshdlfhsdlfhlsdfkhljk"

Comment: Pues eso puede ser la causa de tu problema

Comment: ya lo arregle, era la cadena de conexion, tenia mal la credencial... alguien la cambio

Comment: Puedes crear una respuesta a tu pregunta para dejar constancia de tu problema y solución para otras personas que acaben en tu misma situación puedan encontrarlo mas facilmente, un saludo!

Comment: no ya lo he hecho antes y siempre me califican en negativo